# Calculate vector endpoint

Tags: math, vector

I want to found the endpoints (X,Y,Z) coordinatas of yellow vector.

In two dimension is very simple, but i want to rotate 45 degrees around Z axis in 3D

in 2D:

```
lenght: 10
start point: 0, 0
end point X=lenght*COS(45deg)=7,07 
end point Z=lenght*SIN(45deg)=7,07
```

How do i calculate X,Y,Z endpoints in 3D?[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you starting with a vector in one position and trying to rotate it into another? If so, what is the starting position of the vector? Is this a programming question? If not, it belongs in the [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the program which has the definition of the input vector and can output the result. Ideally implement a function working on input and producing the output structurally, even if incorrectly. Then we can discuss how to change your program to meet the needs.

Comment: redefined: in 1. step, yellow vector end position in 10,0,0 -> 2. step, increment degrees from X axis, +45 degrees -> 3. step rotate the vector endpoint around Z axis with +45 degrees, what is the vector new endpoint coordinatas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. step, yellow vector end position in 10,0,0 ->
> 2. step, increment degrees from X axis, +45 degrees ->
> 3. step rotate the vector endpoint around Z axis with +45 degrees, what is the vector new endpoint coordinatas?

You use some unconventional terminology. Particularly it is not clear what "*increment degrees from X axis, +45 degrees*" means. Anyway this is probably solvable with [rotation matricies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions). I assume that step #2 means "rotate along the Y-axis by 45 degrees".

So this gives us:

**Step 1** `v1 = (10,0,0)`

**Step 2** rotate along the Y-axis by 45 degrees. So we should multiply our vector by a matrix:

```
cos(45)   0   sin(45)
0         1   0
-sin(45)  0   cos(45)
```

which gives us `v2 = (10*sqrt(2)/2, 0, 10*sqrt(2)/2) = (5*sqrt(2), 0, 5*sqrt(2))`

**Step 3** rotate the vector endpoint around Z axis with +45 degrees. So we should multiply our vector `v2` by a matrix:

```
cos(45)  -sin(45)  0
sin(45)  cos(45)   0
0         0        1
```

which gives us  `v3 = (5, 5, 5*sqrt(2))`.

P.S. Note that by doing those 2 rotations you don't get the "middle line" of the 3 axis as one might think, because that vector  obviously has all 3 components equal.